# R: Copy a value from a specific row (that is part of a group) to a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
RowID   ID1     ID2     ID3     Word1       Word2       Word3       Letter  
1       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       t
2       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       h
3       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       e
4       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       n
5       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       i
6       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       c
7       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       e
8       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       a
9       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       p
10      1       2       3       the         nice        apple       p
11      1       2       3       the         nice        apple       l
12      1       2       3       the         nice        apple       e
13      6       7       8       yes         did         you         y
14      6       7       8       yes         did         you         e
15      6       7       8       yes         did         you         s
16      6       7       8       yes         did         you         d
17      6       7       8       yes         did         you         i
18      6       7       8       yes         did         you         d
19      6       7       8       yes         did         you         y
20      6       7       8       yes         did         you         o
21      6       7       8       yes         did         you         u
```

I would like to copy values of from specific rows (based on a conditional select or something similar) to a new column. I want to target the last letter of the second word (value in `Letter` as in `Word2`), which in the case of these examples are these rows:

```
7       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       e
18      6       7       8       yes         did         you         d
```

And then add a new column `LastLetterWord2` to the dataframe, like this:

```
RowID   ID1     ID2     ID3     Word1       Word2       Word3       Letter  LastLetterWord2
1       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       t       e   
2       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       h       e
3       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       e       e
4       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       n       e
5       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       i       e
6       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       c       e
7       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       e       e
8       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       a       e
9       1       2       3       the         nice        apple       p       e
10      1       2       3       the         nice        apple       p       e
11      1       2       3       the         nice        apple       l       e
12      1       2       3       the         nice        apple       e       e
13      6       7       8       yes         did         you         y       d
14      6       7       8       yes         did         you         e       d
15      6       7       8       yes         did         you         s       d
16      6       7       8       yes         did         you         d       d
17      6       7       8       yes         did         you         i       d
18      6       7       8       yes         did         you         d       d
19      6       7       8       yes         did         you         y       d
20      6       7       8       yes         did         you         o       d
21      6       7       8       yes         did         you         u       d
```

Is it possible to do this in R, and if so, how? (I'm not much of an expert in R yet). One possible problem might be that words are not unique and can occur many times and in different positions (so as Word1, Word2 or Word3).

Comment: To me it's not completely clear what you're asking...(I read it quickly and gave an answer but it's probably not exactly what you want). What is not clear to me is how the two rows (7 and 18) influence the letters in LastLetterWord2... it seems like you're just taking the last letter of Word2 of each row, nothing else...

Comment: I'm actually trying to extract the value in the Letter column that matches the last letter in Word2, rather than just getting the value by using substr on the column Word2. I need this for a few other columns as well that don't have anything in common, but in general, I'm looking for something like "if in this row Letter matches the last letter in Word2, get the value from column X"

Comment: so, once you created the column LastLetterWord2 you can use that to filter the rows you want, e.g. `values <- DF[DF$LastLetterWord2  == DF$Letter,ColumnX]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `substr` and `nchar` you can easily create a new column with the last letter of `Word2` column :

```
DF$LastLetterWord2 <- substr(DF$Word2,nchar(DF$Word2),nchar(DF$Word2))

> DF
   RowID ID1 ID2 ID3 Word1 Word2 Word3 Letter LastLetterWord2
1      1   1   2   3   the  nice apple      t               e
2      2   1   2   3   the  nice apple      h               e
3      3   1   2   3   the  nice apple      e               e
4      4   1   2   3   the  nice apple      n               e
5      5   1   2   3   the  nice apple      i               e
6      6   1   2   3   the  nice apple      c               e
7      7   1   2   3   the  nice apple      e               e
8      8   1   2   3   the  nice apple      a               e
9      9   1   2   3   the  nice apple      p               e
10    10   1   2   3   the  nice apple      p               e
11    11   1   2   3   the  nice apple      l               e
12    12   1   2   3   the  nice apple      e               e
13    13   6   7   8   yes   did   you      y               d
14    14   6   7   8   yes   did   you      e               d
15    15   6   7   8   yes   did   you      s               d
16    16   6   7   8   yes   did   you      d               d
17    17   6   7   8   yes   did   you      i               d
18    18   6   7   8   yes   did   you      d               d
19    19   6   7   8   yes   did   you      y               d
20    20   6   7   8   yes   did   you      o               d
21    21   6   7   8   yes   did   you      u               d
```

Answer (score 0):

using str_sub from the stringr library will also do the same:

```
df$LastLetterWord2 =stringr::str_sub(df$Word2, start = -1, end = -1) # using minus to indicate from the end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your table is `DF`.

**DATA**

```
RowID  <- 1:21
ID1    <- c(rep(1,12),rep(6,9))
ID2    <- c(rep(2,12),rep(7,9))
ID3    <- c(rep(3,12),rep(8,9))
Word1  <- c(rep("the",12),rep("yes",9))
Word2  <- c(rep("nice",12),rep("did",9))
Word3  <- c(rep("apple",12),rep("you",9))
Letter <- c("t","h","e","n","i","c","e","a","p","p","l","e","y","e","s","d","i","d","y","o","u")
DF     <- data.frame(RowID,ID1,ID2,ID3,Word1,Word2,Word3,Letter)
```

**Command**

`nchar` returns the size of character vector. `substring` extracts letters from character vector.

```
numberofcharacter  <- data.frame(apply(DF,2,nchar))
DF$LastLetterWord2 <- substring(DF$Word2,numberofcharacter$Word2,numberofcharacter$Word2)
```

**RESULT**

```
   RowID ID1 ID2 ID3 Word1 Word2 Word3 Letter LastLetterWord2
1      1   1   2   3   the  nice apple      t               e
2      2   1   2   3   the  nice apple      h               e
3      3   1   2   3   the  nice apple      e               e
4      4   1   2   3   the  nice apple      n               e
5      5   1   2   3   the  nice apple      i               e
6      6   1   2   3   the  nice apple      c               e
7      7   1   2   3   the  nice apple      e               e
8      8   1   2   3   the  nice apple      a               e
9      9   1   2   3   the  nice apple      p               e
10    10   1   2   3   the  nice apple      p               e
11    11   1   2   3   the  nice apple      l               e
12    12   1   2   3   the  nice apple      e               e
13    13   6   7   8   yes   did   you      y               d
14    14   6   7   8   yes   did   you      e               d
15    15   6   7   8   yes   did   you      s               d
16    16   6   7   8   yes   did   you      d               d
17    17   6   7   8   yes   did   you      i               d
18    18   6   7   8   yes   did   you      d               d
19    19   6   7   8   yes   did   you      y               d
20    20   6   7   8   yes   did   you      o               d
21    21   6   7   8   yes   did   you      u               d
```